# Save Site as Template error

Tags: 2010, list-template

I am receiving the error when i try to save list as template .

> The server is out of memory. There is no memory on the server to run your program. Please contact your administrator with this problem.
>
> Exception occurred. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020009 (DISP_E_EXCEPTION)) .

The memory is fine , how do i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When you save your SharePoint site as a template, you’re saving the
>   overall framework of the site – its lists and libraries, views and
>   forms, and workflows. In addition to these components, you can include
>   the contents of the site in the template, for example, the documents
>   stored in the document libraries. This could be useful to provide
>   sample content for users to get started with. Keep in mind that this
>   could also increase the size of your template beyond the default 50 MB
>   site template limit.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/save-a-sharepoint-site-as-a-template-HA101782501.aspx

edit (http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/64f2a249-fbec-4c70-af12-7f81dd2c4c89/increase-sharepoint-list-or-site-template-size-limit-get-an-error-using-powershell)

```
STSADM -o setproperty -pn max-template-document-size -pv 500000000
```

or (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2672009)

```
STSADM -o setproperty -pn large-file-chunk-size -pv 1073741824
```

Comment: is this true for "Save List as template" as well ?

Comment: tipically, there are always limits for UI stuff (upload, templates, etc). "By default, you can create a list template that contains up to 10 megabytes (MB) of content. Server administrators can increase this size limit, if necessary." http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/manage-list-templates-HA010099156.aspx